# Make the swipe back gesture bigger for react native navigation V2 in IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using the latest `^2.1.3-snapshot.49` version of Wix's `React Native Navigation`. On IPhone XR (IOS 12.1), it is very difficult to trigger the swipe back gesture / pop gesture to go back to the previous screen. I have to make an effort to swipe from the very edge of the screen and sometimes, I have to try several times to get the pop gesture to work. It isn't as natural and easy as in Safari.

I use the stack layout for the test:

```
            Navigation.setRoot({
                root: {
                    stack: {
                        id: "centerStack",
                        children: [
                            {
                                component: {
                                    name: "Home",
                                }
                            },
                        ]

                    },
                }
            });
```

Have any RNN users found the back swipe vert difficult to trigger?

I saw that the other navigation library, `React Navigation`, provides an option to make the back swipe area bigger. Does RNN provide a similar option?

Comment: I finally made the move and migrated back to React Navigation. It solved the problem. The back swipe is as natural as in Safari. Plus, I don't see any performance difference.